# scraping pdf files multiple pages from url

Tags: python, pandas

I want to scrape the information on this PDF in python. I'm not sure where to start because it isn't organized at all. I'm used to scraping HTML. I tried converting it to HTML and that didn't really help.

How would you try to scrape this PDF? Here is a link to the PDFs (any will work, they're all similar): https://portal.charitycommissioner.je/Public-Register/
https://www.gov.im/media/1371147/publicindex_latest-15121-v2.pdf

Thank you for any help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is organized - it's in a "table" - [pdfplumber](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#extracting-tables) works well for this.

[image: pdfplumber example]

Once you have settings that correctly match your data you can `.extract_table()`

```
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd

pdf = pdfplumber.open('file.pdf')

page = pdf.pages[0]
table = page.extract_table(
    dict(vertical_strategy="text", keep_blank_chars=True)
)

df = pd.DataFrame(table)
```

Comment: @KarIT please the full code for the above, please? resulting in attribute error extract_table()

Comment: @KarIT https://portal.charitycommissioner.je/Public-Register/ looking to extract this one too, please?

Comment: @KarIT, thanks a lot, to get all pages and store as CSV please?

Comment: after loop resulting in just one page still